# Как правильно преобразовать объект в строку, чтобы переменную ss воспринимало как текст?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".next").click(function(){
    
        for(let i = 0; i < 5 ;i++)
        {
          let ss = $(".hidden > img").attr("src").get(i); 
          $(".big-image img").attr("src", ss );/* ss должна возвращать значение атрибута src */
        };
    
      });
    
    });
```

html:

```
 <div class="gallery-box">
            <div class="view">
                <div class="big-image"><img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image11"></div>
                <a href="#" class="prev">previos</a>
                <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
            </div>
    
    <div class="hidden" style="display: none;">
    
        <img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
        <img src="imadges/gallery/image2.jpeg" alt="image2">
        <img src="imadges/gallery/image3.jpeg" alt="image3">
        <img src="imadges/gallery/image4.jpg" alt="image4">
        <img src="imadges/gallery/image5.jpg" alt="image5">
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let ss = $(".hidden > img").eq(i).attr("src");
```

Цикл бессмысленный, видна в конце концов будет только последняя картинка.

У Вас действительно папка называется `imadges`?

---

```
let index = 0;
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  let ss = $(".hidden > img").eq(index++).attr("src"); 
  $(".big-image img").attr("src", ss);
  index = index % $(".hidden > img").length;
});
```

Comment: $(".big-image img").attr("src", ss ); что делать с это строкой,  как записать ss? Да, imadges, я знаю)

Comment: @Netervey Ничего не делать. Не понял вопрос.

Comment: У меня браузер не воспринимает ссылку .next , просто страничка перезагружается, может сделать так [ss] или так `${ss}` или так toString(ss)? точнее добавляет решетку в конец адреса: TheSite/index.html#

Answer (score 1):

На сколько нужен цикл - не ясно. А в целом вот:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next").click(function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            let ss = $(".hidden > img").get(i); //.attr("src");      
            console.log($(ss).attr('src'));     
            
            //или 
            ss = $(".hidden > img").eq(i).attr("src");
            console.log(ss); 
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-box">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="big-image"><img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image11"></div>
    <a href="#" class="prev">previos</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" style="display: none;">

    <img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image2.jpeg" alt="image2">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image3.jpeg" alt="image3">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image4.jpg" alt="image4">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image5.jpg" alt="image5">

  </div>
```

Comment: в общем c картинок в классе .hidden должны браться ссылки на изображения по очереди и с каждым нажатием .next картинка класса .big-mage должна обновлять свой адрес. Картинок 5 и цикл на 5 раз(наверное)

Comment: @Netervey нет, цикл не нужен. Нужен отдельный счётчик, который будет прибавлять +1 при кажом клике на next. Ну а в `.get` или `eq` будет подставляться именно значение этой переменной

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал скачанный файл jquery, в котором просто путь к файлу возвращался абсолютный через attr. Простите, наверное у меня была библиотека столетней давности